# How to use "Query value" in Amazon connect CTI flow?

Tags: cti, amazon-connect, amazon-connect-salesforce-cti

Using Managed Package [Amazon Connect CTI Adapter](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EJH4yUAH).

What I am trying to do is finding any existing case when a call connects(onAccepted event).
**search and screen pop block** is returning a contact id then I'm trying to query a open Case with the contactId using **Query Value** block.

Query: select Id from Case where contactId=:$.action.uid-23.Id
[image]

Getting this error

> "MALFORMED_QUERY: \nselect Id from Case where
> contactId=:$.action.uid-23.Id\n
> ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:36\nBind variables only allowed in Apex code"

How to access the return variable or is there any other solution?

Comment: Looks like an issue with missing reference. Can you try `select Id from Case where contactId=:$.action.uid-23.results.Id` and let me know if it works. Thx

Comment: @Swetha no same thing.

"MALFORMED_QUERY: select Id from Case where contactId=:$.action.uid-23.results.Id ERROR at Row:1:Column:36\nBind variables only allowed in Apex code".

Any idea how we can find existing case otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into the exact same sort of issue. It appears that you can't join strings and arguments in a Query block directly, so my solution for this was to build the query outside the Query block via Join Strings, and then use the ValueOf drop down to populate the Query string.

As an example below the First Join Strings block has `SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE CaseNumber = '` and `$.actions.uid-23.results.value` as the two arguments, where `$.actions.uid-23.results.value` was the CaseNumber attribute attached to that Contact retrieved in the Get Contact Attribute block.

The second Join Strings has `$.actions.uid-21.results.string` and `'` as the arguments and the Query block references the value coming out of the second Join Strings block, where `$.actions.uid-21.results.string` is the output of the first Join Strings block.

[image: Join Strings to for Query]

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing the flow as well. Needed to extract the Id using Extract Value block.