# Salesforce Extract Value CTI Block - CTI Flows

Tags: apex, cti

I've been working with CTI Flows for creating call logs upon ending a call. I want to query a Case record using the Query Value block and then extracting the Id of the Case and assign it to the WhatId field on the Call Log record.

I found a similar post ([How to use "Query value" in Amazon connect CTI flow?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/388145/how-to-use-query-value-in-amazon-connect-cti-flow)) on how to use the Query Value Block and was able to form my query properly, the only issue I'm having is not being able to properly extract the Id from the query using the Extract Value CTI Block. The help text on the description really doesn't help understand what needs to be defined when pairing it with a Query block and I get no error message but just don't get any return value from the Extract Value block.

The query is basically the following.

SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE Description = contactId; (amazon connect contactid from the call);

In a different CTI Flow, I create a Case record and assign the contactId to the Description field. That part is tested and working. The issue is just being able to find this Case record and extracting the Id to assign to the WhatId field on the Call Log.

Here's a Screenshot of the Extract Value CTI block. targetField and keyPath are the two parameters that are needed for this block. I've tried setting targetField as Id (I want to extract the Id field from the Query) and setting keyPath as 0.Id (which is actually what the help text gives as an example for extracting the id of the first result of a list of records). This doesn't return anything and I need to be able to find the case record.

[image]

Also tried referencing the actual output of the query block and adding .id to the end of the value.
[image]